# Does Microsoft Azure or Google instance supports WIndows server 2003?

Tags: azure, cloud

My client need to deploy an application which is supporting windows Server 2003 OS . Not higher than windows server 2003.
He is looking for a cloud solution.
Amazon Awa single cpu instance supports but when he is upgrading the cpu, his application stops working.

Does Microsoft Azure or Google Cloud server supports Windows Server 2003 OS ?

Comment: In general, "cloud solution" and "10+ year old software" don't go together.

Answer (score 0):

No, they will not support it.

I know these places support it, [ResellerChoice](http://www.resellerchoice.com) and [YokuCloud](http://www.yokucloud.com)